# Malformed String ValueError ast.literal_eval() with String representation of Tuple

Tags: python, parsing, python-2.x, abstract-syntax-tree, representation

I'm trying to read in a string representation of a Tuple from a file, and add the tuple to a list. Here's the relevant code.

```
raw_data = userfile.read().split('\n')
for a in raw_data : 
    print a
    btc_history.append(ast.literal_eval(a))
```

Here is the output:

```
(Decimal('11.66985'), Decimal('0E-8'))
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "./goxnotify.py", line 74, in <module>
    main()
  File "./goxnotify.py", line 68, in main
    local.load_user_file(username,btc_history)
  File "/home/unix-dude/Code/GoxNotify/local_functions.py", line 53, in load_user_file
    btc_history.append(ast.literal_eval(a))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 80, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)

  `File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 58, in _convert
   return tuple(map(_convert, node.elts))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 79, in _convert
   raise ValueError('malformed string')
   ValueError: malformed string
```

Comment: If it's trusted input - could you eval it?

Comment: Thats what I tried originally, it gave me SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing.  It is trusted input.

Comment: This *is* annoying...

Comment: Did you follow up why it is giving you that SyntaxError? Normally, eval() is something no one would ever recommend you use, but since it is trusted input, that would be the easiest way of doing what you need.

Comment: See my answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval/68732605#68732605

Answer (score 49):

`ast.literal_eval` (located in `ast.py`) parses the tree with `ast.parse` first, then it evaluates the code with quite an ugly recursive function, interpreting the parse tree elements and replacing them with their literal equivalents. Unfortunately the code is not at all expandable, so to add `Decimal` to the code you need to copy all the code and start over.

For a slightly easier approach, you can use `ast.parse` module to parse the expression, and then the `ast.NodeVisitor` or `ast.NodeTransformer` to ensure that there is no unwanted syntax or unwanted variable accesses. Then compile with `compile` and `eval` to get the result.

The code is a bit different from `literal_eval` in that this code actually uses `eval`, but in my opinion is simpler to understand and one does not need to dig too deep into AST trees. It specifically only allows some syntax, explicitly forbidding for example lambdas, attribute accesses (`foo.__dict__` is very evil), or accesses to any names that are not deemed safe. It parses your expression fine, and as an extra I also added `Num` (float and integer), list and dictionary literals.

Also, works the same on 2.7 and 3.3

```
import ast
import decimal

source = "(Decimal('11.66985'), Decimal('1e-8'),"\
    "(1,), (1,2,3), 1.2, [1,2,3], {1:2})"

tree = ast.parse(source, mode='eval')

# using the NodeTransformer, you can also modify the nodes in the tree,
# however in this example NodeVisitor could do as we are raising exceptions
# only.
class Transformer(ast.NodeTransformer):
    ALLOWED_NAMES = set(['Decimal', 'None', 'False', 'True'])
    ALLOWED_NODE_TYPES = set([
        'Expression', # a top node for an expression
        'Tuple',      # makes a tuple
        'Call',       # a function call (hint, Decimal())
        'Name',       # an identifier...
        'Load',       # loads a value of a variable with given identifier
        'Str',        # a string literal

        'Num',        # allow numbers too
        'List',       # and list literals
        'Dict',       # and dicts...
    ])

    def visit_Name(self, node):
        if not node.id in self.ALLOWED_NAMES:
            raise RuntimeError("Name access to %s is not allowed" % node.id)

        # traverse to child nodes
        return self.generic_visit(node)

    def generic_visit(self, node):
        nodetype = type(node).__name__
        if nodetype not in self.ALLOWED_NODE_TYPES:
            raise RuntimeError("Invalid expression: %s not allowed" % nodetype)

        return ast.NodeTransformer.generic_visit(self, node)


transformer = Transformer()

# raises RuntimeError on invalid code
transformer.visit(tree)

# compile the ast into a code object
clause = compile(tree, '<AST>', 'eval')

# make the globals contain only the Decimal class,
# and eval the compiled object
result = eval(clause, dict(Decimal=decimal.Decimal))

print(result)
```

Comment: Do note that in Pythons 3.4+ and so, there is a new node type for the likes of None, False and True

Answer (score 34):

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) for `ast.literal_eval()`:

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python expression. **The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.**

`Decimal` isn't on the list of things allowed by `ast.literal_eval()`.

Comment: Bleh, I was hoping the fact its a tuple at its highest level would make it ok. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: I found a roundabout way to fix my problem I just laid a bounty for but I want to see a higher quality solution from someone else, particularly NPE since he already has some authority in this thread.

Comment: @jdero: If you are faced with untrusted input, the only secure solution is to create a custom parser to process the input string.

Comment: @NPE What would a custom parser look like? If you update your answer with a bit more beef I'd be glad to accept it.

Comment: Actually you would not need a custom *parser*, it is enough that you use the Python parser and then interpret AST trees

Comment: @AnttiHaapala If you would like to provide another, more thorough answer, I'd be glad to accept it.

Comment: That is helpful since I had an array and apparently I am not going to get very far with the array data structure

Answer (score 7):

in my case I solved with:

```
my_string = my_string.replace(':false', ':False').replace(':true', ':True')
ast.literal_eval(my_string)
```

Comment: I needed spaces after the colons:

    ````my_string = my_string.replace(': false', ': False').replace(': true', ': True')````

after moving from Python 3.6 to Python 3.10 (parsing a Django 4 queryset.explain(format='JSON'))

Answer (score 4):

Use `eval()` instead of `ast.literal_eval()` if the input is trusted (which it is in your case).

```
raw_data = userfile.read().split('\n')
for a in raw_data : 
    print a
    btc_history.append(eval(a))
```

This works for me in Python 3.6.0

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I think found a very simple answer, in case anybody needs it.

If you put string quotes inside your string ("'hello'"), ast_literaleval() will understand it perfectly.

You can use a simple function:

```
    def doubleStringify(a):
        b = "\'" + a + "\'"
        return b
```

Or probably more suitable for this example:

```
    def perfectEval(anonstring):
        try:
            ev = ast.literal_eval(anonstring)
            return ev
        except ValueError:
            corrected = "\'" + anonstring + "\'"
            ev = ast.literal_eval(corrected)
            return ev
```

Comment: That just makes it evaluate it to a string. Look at repr(ev).