# Read the written list of dictionaries from file in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a file which is a list of dictionaries in this way:

`[{'text': 'this is the text', 'filed1': 'something1', 'filed2': 'something2', 'subtexts': [{'body': 'body of subtext1', 'date': 'xx'}, {'body': 'body of subtext2', 'date': 'yy'}}]`

The list of nested dictionaries and lists can have multiples dicts and lists inside. I want to read the file which is written exactly like this in python and create a data structure (list of dictionaries). How can it be done knowing it's not json but it has written to file by `file.write(str(list))` where list is something we want to read back from file?

Comment: Possibly a dumb question, but have you tried just rebuilding a string by concatenating each line in the file?

Comment: The file is one line of a list of dictionaries.

Comment: I'm confused then. The answer by Randy C should work, your dictionary is presented in two blocks of code so I assumed the problem was that is was split by `\n`. What goes wrong with `json.load`?

Comment: Are you able to read the file back in as a single string? In that case you could use `json.dumps(string)`

Comment: This is no JavaScript Object Notation, but "Python Literal Notation".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) which is a safe way of evaluating Python literals [(as opposed to `eval`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval) into actual data structures.

That is:

```
import ast

with open('file.txt') as f:
    data = ast.literal_eval(f.read())
```

If you have something beyond the supported types (strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and `None`), you can [use my recipe in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18178379/918959).

Comment: I am still very much learning; can you explain which way this method is "safe" compared to my answer of just using `eval()`?

Comment: If the text is from untrusted sources, then with `eval()` it can contain **any** python code, including installing malware on your system. `literal_eval` rejects any python code that is not literals/constants of the types listed in my answer.

Comment: That still leaves me a bit perplexed. I understand that this is not OP's question, but I can't see how you could, for example, secrete a `print` statement in a data structure that then gets executed by any operation you might perform on a data structure

Comment: Nevermind [found it here](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) thanks :)