# Problems while reformating this json output?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, python-requests

I am calling an API with requests as follows:

```
def get_data(text, url='api.com'):
    r = requests.get(url,
                     params={'key': '<My KEY>',
                             'in': text
                             'fj': 'm'})
    if r.status_code != requests.codes.ok:
        return np.nan
    return r.json()
```

Each row looks like this:

```
{'A': [{'param0': 'a',
   'param1': 'b',
   'param2': '342',
   'param3': '$ 2342',
   'param4': '234',
   'param5': '555'}],
 'status': {'code': '0', 'credits': '1', 'msg': 'OK'}}
```

**How can I transform each column in to a tuple like this:**

```
[('param0','a'), ('param1','b'), ('param2', '342'), ('param3', '$ 2342'), ('param5', '555')]
```

At first instance I tried to parse the above output, however I can not access since I get:

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'float'
```

Any idea of how to get the list of tuples?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d = {'A': [{'param0': 'a',
   'param1': 'b',
   'param2': '342',
   'param3': '$ 2342',
   'param4': '234',
   'param5': '555'}],
 'status': {'code': '0', 'credits': '1', 'msg': 'OK'}}

[i for i in d['A'][0].items()]
```

out:

```
[('param1', 'b'),
 ('param5', '555'),
 ('param0', 'a'),
 ('param4', '234'),
 ('param3', '$ 2342'),
 ('param2', '342')]
```

There's also a builtin JSON **decoder**, in case you're dealing with JSON data:

```
>>> import requests

>>> r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events')
>>> r.json()
[{u'repository': {u'open_issues': 0, u'url': 'https://github.com/...
```

Comment: Thanks, I got this error: `ValueError: malformed node or string:`. I guess is an ecoding issue... since the type of the function output is a dict

Comment: @john doe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611352/malformed-string-valueerror-ast-literal-eval-with-string-representation-of-tup. this error is off topic of this question.

Comment: Thanks again!... I tried to use the ast and still the same, what can I do?

Comment: @john doe you should post another question about it, it's hard to answer a question in comment. and please accept this answer to close this question.

Comment: I tried to reformat the output of the json, check my update!

Comment: @john doe  r.json() will return a python object, no need to decode it .

Comment: Thanks, from the start I tried the json built in, and I have the aforementioned issue