# Logic issue in Python code

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, dictionary

I am new to Python,I am writing a simple program

Input

```
{'messagingservice': 'build4', 
 'oltpdatabase': 'build1', 
 'paymentsdatabase': 'build2', 
 'restserver': 'build5', 
 'PESQL': 'build3', 
 'configdatabase': 'build1'}
```

expected output is as below

```
{'build4': 'messagingservice', 
 'build5': 'restserver', 
 'build2': 'paymentsdatabase', 
 'build3': 'PESQL', 
 'build1': 'oltpdatabase,configdatabase '}
```

Below is the code I have used ...

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import json
import ast
from sys import argv
data = json.dumps(argv[1]);
json_to_unicode = json.loads(data)
unicode_to_dic = ast.literal_eval(json_to_unicode);
print(unicode_to_dic);
result_dic={};
data='';
for k,v in unicode_to_dic.iteritems():
  if v in result_dic:
    data=data.join((result_dic[v],','));
    print (data)
    result_dic[v]=data

  else:
    result_dic[v]=k;

print(result_dic)
```

Actual output is:

```
{'build4': 'messagingservice', 
 'build5': 'restserver', 
 'build2': 'paymentsdatabase', 
 'build3': 'PESQL', 
 'build1': 'oltpdatabase,'}
```

Missing one more value.

Comment: Can you provide a short explanation of what this code is supposed to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Malformed String ValueError ast.literal\_eval() with String representation of Tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611352/malformed-string-valueerror-ast-literal-eval-with-string-representation-of-tup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your join did not join the new item

```
result_dic={}
data=''
for k,v in d.iteritems():
   if v in result_dic.keys():
      data=data.join((result_dic[v],', ',k))
      result_dic[v]=data
   else:
      result_dic[v]=k

print(result_dic)
```

returns

```
{'build4': 'messagingservice', 'build5': 'restserver', 'build2':   'paymentsdatabase', 'build3': 'PESQL', 'build1': 'oltpdatabase, configdatabase'}
```

you could also use `collections.Counter`

```
from collections import Counter
new =Counter() 
d={'messagingservice': 'build4', 'oltpdatabase': 'build1', 'paymentsdatabase': 'build2', 'restserver': 'build5', 'PESQL': 'build3','configdatabase': 'build1'} 
for k,v in d.items():
    if new[v]:
        new[v]+=', '+k
    else:
        new[v]=k
print new
```

returns

```
Counter({'build1': 'oltpdatabase, configdatabase',
         'build2': 'paymentsdatabase',
         'build3': 'PESQL',
         'build4': 'messagingservice',
         'build5': 'restserver'})
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), that could make the program much easier:

```
unicode_to_dic = {
 'messagingservice': 'build4', 
 'oltpdatabase': 'build1', 
 'paymentsdatabase': 'build2', 
 'restserver': 'build5', 
 'PESQL': 'build3', 
 'configdatabase': 'build1'}

from collections import defaultdict

res = defaultdict(list)

# find all keys that have the same value
for key, value in unicode_to_dic.items():
    res[value].append(key)

# convert the list of keys to a string seperated by ','
for key, value in res.items():
    res[key] = ','.join(value)

# Convert it to  a normal dict - that's optional because defaultdict behaves just
# like a normal dict (in most circumstances at least).
dict(res)

# {'build1': 'oltpdatabase,configdatabase',
#  'build2': 'paymentsdatabase',
#  'build3': 'PESQL',
#  'build4': 'messagingservice',
#  'build5': 'restserver'}
```

I haven't debugged your algorithm but there are several things that stand out:

- Python doesn't need `;` at the end of lines.
- `str.join` is actually called as `seperator.join(list_of_words_to_be_joined)`. You used the seperator as input for the function.

Comment: Thanks a lot , I spent whole day to crack this .. :)

Comment: @VetrivelkumarPandi No problem. Don't forget to [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) all helpful answers and [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the most helpful one.

Answer (score 1):

`data.join` doesn't do what you think. What you want is:

```
result_dic[v] += ',' + k
```