# Read a dictionary from file and convert it to python data type dict

Tags: python, dictionary

File contains the following data:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c04cc50792d7153282a0874"), "Name" : "Nimish", "Marks" : "100" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c04cc61792d7153282a0875"), "Name" : "Ayush", "Marks" : "78" }
```

I need these data to be converted to list of dictionaries.
Have tried `ast.literal_eval()` but it generates `malformed node or string` error.

Comment: what is `ObjectId("5c04cc50792d7153282a0874")` there ?

Comment: @mehrdad-pedramfar I think it's unique ID created by MongoDB for each record.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Malformed String ValueError ast.literal\_eval() with String representation of Tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611352/malformed-string-valueerror-ast-literal-eval-with-string-representation-of-tup)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `'` before and after of `ObjectId("xxxxxx")`, then convert to dictionary.
sample code is

```
import json
from pprint import pprint
import ast

with open('data2.txt') as f:
    data = f.read().replace("ObjectId(", "'ObjectId(").replace(")", ")'").replace("\n", ",");

listDict = ast.literal_eval(data)
print(listDict)
```

output is

```
({'_id': 'ObjectId("5c04cc50792d7153282a0874")', 'Name': 'Nimish', 'Marks': '100'}, {'_id': 'ObjectId("5c04cc61792d7153282a0875")', 'Name': 'Ayush', 'Marks': '78'})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to replace the ObjectId pattern, then `json.loads()` will convert it  to dictionary.

```
import json
import re

raw_string = '{"_id" : ObjectId("5c04cc50792d7153282a0874"), "Name" : "Nimish", "Marks" : "100" }'

# Use regex to replace the ObjectId and parantheses
parsed_data = re.sub(r'ObjectId\((.*)\)',r'\1',raw_string)

dict_dump = json.loads(parsed_data)
print(type(dict_dump))
print(dict_dump)
```