# Save partial function call in json file

Tags: python, json, functools

I have a dictionary to store N number of partial function calls.

```
dict_ = {1: partial(FUNCTION, ARG1,ARG2,ARG3 )}
```

which works fine.

If I store this dictionary inside a .json file I have quotes around my partial call

```
dict_ =    {"1":"partial(FUNCTION, ARG1,ARG2,ARG3 )"}
```

How do I get rid of this quotes in order to execute the code?

```
ast.literal_eval(dict_ ['1'])
```

returns `ValueError('malformed node or string:..`

Comment: You might be better off using a different serialization format, since json isn't really designed to store anything other than numbers/strings/dicts/lists. How do you feel about `pickle`?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18178379/  https://stackoverflow.com/a/14611535/