# Check if string is type

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-namespace

I wish to parse keyword arguments to determine if they also refer to types, such as in the case below:

```py
from inspect import isclass
def convert(converting, **kwargs):
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        if value and isclass(eval(key[1:])):
            return(eval(key[1:])(converting))
string = "Hello!"
print(convert(string, _list = True))
```

I am well aware that `eval` has security concerns for unknown strings, which is why I am looking for a safer method of determining the type from the keyword name.

Built-in types can be checked via `import builtins; isclass(getattr(builtins, 'str'))`, as per [a_guest's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3767239/a-guest) comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3767239/a-guest), but I am still stumped on how to check other classes. Perhaps `isclass(getattr(globals(), key[1:]))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python normally looks up names using LEGB. Since you have no non-locals, you can ignore `E`. You know that you don't have a local name, so `L` is gone too. So the equivalent lookup would indeed be a call to `globals` and a search of `builtins`.

You don't need a dictionary if all you care about are the keys. That way, you explicitly pass in simple strings and don't need to play games with extra characters:

```
import builtins
from inspect import isclass

def convert(target, *names):
    for name in names:
        obj = globals().get(name, getattr(builtins, name, None))
        if isclass(obj):
            return obj(target)
    return converting
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply; however, while `__builtins__` could not find `list`, `builtins` the module could. In addition, I had to use `(globals)`. Shall I make the necessary changes and accept this answer?

Comment: @ShadowRylander. Please forgive the typos and thanks for the offer to fix. I've fixed the errors. If anything else is missing, please feel free to edit.

Comment: Nope; matches up! Thanks for all the help! Accepted!